How do I set the folder name for the selenium grid node from python code
I have a pretty simple looking docker file for setting up a selenium standalone service:
services:
  selenium-standalone:
    image: selenium/standalone-docker:4.18.1-20240224
    container_name: selenium-docker
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      - ./config.toml:/opt/bin/config.toml
      - /tmp/target:/opt/selenium/assets
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

problem is that after I am done executing lot of parallel tests, I need to go through each folder (that is located inside /Assets/target/nodeName) to view the recordings. thats because folders are named after nodes and its impossible to tell them apart.
Each scenario I execute has specific tags that are used for each thread that is being recorded. I want to somehow pass that variable to selenium to name those folders correctly.
My other idea was to set a custom capability to chrome, read the sessionCapabilites.json file and rename the folders based on the tags that I provided there. but I cant seem to pass any custom capabilities to a chrome driver.
attempt code:
#!/bin/bash

find ../Assets/target/ -name sessionCapabilities.json | while read json_file; do
  dir=$(dirname "$json_file")

  tags=$(jq -r '.tags' "$json_file")

  if [ ! -z "$tags" ] && [ "$tags" != "null" ]; then
    parent_dir=$(dirname "$dir")
    new_dir_name="$parent_dir/$tags"

    if [ ! -d "$new_dir_name" ]; then
      mv "$dir" "$new_dir_name"
    else
      echo "Directory $new_dir_name already exists. Skipping."
    fi
  else
    echo "tags is empty or null in $json_file. Skipping."
  fi
done

